# terminal error on setting up ruby2&rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rvm, linux-mint

preface: my computer distribution : linuxmint  15

my install step :

1. install `rvm` , no problem
2. install `ruby 2.0.0` through `rvm install 2.0.0` no problem
3. install `rails 4` through `gem install rails --version 4.0.0.rc1 --no-ri --no-rdoc`,complete!
4. **BUT**, when i type `rails -v` in my terminal, error rails !

that's the error log:

`` /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- /home/sergio/config/boot (LoadError)
    from /home/sergio/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>' ``

**BTW**,there is no a folder named `config` in my $HOME,can anyone tell what's happened? and how to fix it !!!

Answer (score 0):

looks like you missed step:

2,5. `rvm use 2.0.0`

you need to repeat rest of the steps `3` and `4`.

Answer (score 0):

an alternative to rvm would be 'rbenv'. if you still have trouble with your setup, consider going through this blog post (of mine). It's how I installed my own rails4 (ruby2) development environment, and documented the steps along the way:

http://blog.parsalabs.com/blog/2013/08/27/setting-up-a-ruby-on-rails-4-development-environment-on-a-clean-mac-os-x-installation/

Hope it helps you as well.